Python Parse a F5 Command output and get to excel
I know there are multiple threads on the same , but posting this question to understand how can i do the below  efficient way in python..
I am trying to parse the output of "show sys performance" from F5  in python  .below is the output :
output =
'''

Sys::Performance Connections
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Active Connections           Current  Average  Max(since 04/09/24 10:04:14)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Connections                      151      133                           158
                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total New Connections(/sec)  Current  Average  Max(since 04/09/24 10:04:14)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Client Connections                22       22                            24
Server Connections                20       20                            22
                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTP Requests(/sec)          Current  Average  Max(since 04/09/24 10:04:14)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTP Requests                      0        0                             0
                           

BIG-IP DNS::DNS-Express Performance

BIG-IP DNS::DNSSEC Performance

Sys::Performance Ramcache
------------------------------------------------------------------------
RAM Cache Utilization(%)  Current  Average  Max(since 04/09/24 10:04:14)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hit Rate                        0        0                             0
Byte Rate                       0        0                             0
Eviction Rate                   0        0                             0

Sys::Performance System
-------------------------------------------------------------------
System CPU Usage(%)  Current  Average  Max(since 04/09/24 10:04:14)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Utilization               15       14                            22
                   
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Memory Used(%)       Current  Average  Max(since 04/09/24 10:04:14)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
TMM Memory Used            2        2                             2
Other Memory Used         84       84                            85
Swap Used                 33       33                            33
                   

Sys::Performance Throughput
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Throughput(bits)(bits/sec)     Current  Average  Max(since 04/09/24 10:04:14)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Service                           9.6M     6.8M                         17.4M
In                                9.6M     6.9M                         17.3M
Out                               9.5M     6.8M                         17.2M
                             
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSL Transactions               Current  Average  Max(since 04/09/24 10:04:14)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSL TPS                              0        0                             0
                             
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Throughput(packets)(pkts/sec)  Current  Average  Max(since 04/09/24 10:04:14)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Service                           1.7K     1.2K                          3.0K
In                                1.6K     1.1K                          2.8K
Out                               1.6K     1.2K                          2.8K
                             

'''

i am doing splitting the lines and then getting the values ...
for example :
tg=output.split("Sys")
tg1=(tg[5].replace("tem","")) ..and so on ...
print(tg1)
CPU Usage(%)  Current  Average  Max(since 04/09/24 11:06:11)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Utilization               13       13                            24

but i know there should be other way to do this , given i doing so much of splitting the lines and taking the values and storing it in a variable...
what i want is get the  CPU,Memory usage  ( current , avergrage ,Max ) .and store then in excel with cpu values in "CPU sheet " , Memory usage in "memory sheet"
so my excel "CPU" sheet  will have like this ..

Please guide me how can i do that .. if some one can write the code , i will do that for all the other fields from output..

You can use regular expressions (Python module re) but splitting the lines is ok, too. If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

You could use pandas to convert the output as a dataframe and then export it to excel. Before creating the dataframe, some cleaning needs to be done. This can be achieved with regular expressions:

from io import StringIO
import re
import os

import pandas as pd

output = {...} # your output string here

# get relevant part between 'System' and 'Sys::'
output = re.search(r"System(.*?)Sys::", output, re.DOTALL).group(1)
# replace more than one space in output by \t to get suitable delimiter
delimiter = "\t"
output = re.sub(r" {2,}", delimiter, output)
# remove lines consisting of dashes
output = re.sub(r"-+\n", "", output)
# process output string as pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(output), sep=delimiter)

# export to excel
file_path = "output.xlsx"
df.to_excel(file_path, index=False)

# open excel file
os.startfile(file_path)


THanks a lot  Christian .. Followed your suggestion .
